# Port vs socket for redis

Tags: performance, redis

I am setting up redis on a server. What the differenece between having it listen to a port or a socket? I guess a socket may be more secure but are there any performance benefits also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unix domain sockets can achieve around 50% more throughput than TCP sockets (as stated in the official Redis documentation) but this also depends on the platform. However the difference tends to decrease if you make good use of [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining).

So if the server and the client are on the same machine you could gain some speed boost by using Unix domain sockets instead.